# How to parse data in data frame columns using python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, parsing

I am bringing in data from a csv file and I am trying to clean up the data. In my data frame I would like to clean up data in columns.

Here is an example:

```
                  Id                                             RecordType




1  {"Id":"868df808-7979-44d8-b16d-5c14e99108e4"                "RecordType":20



2  {"Id":"8e1140a9-10f3-4113-ada0-6695d24e39df"                "RecordType":20



3  {"Id":"d2aa4e1d-9825-4caf-b409-28f512ce3d87"                "RecordType":20
```

In column 'Id', I would like to parse out {"Id": from the column
and in column 'RecordType', I would like to parse out "RecordType":

So basically I am looking to remove anything before the":"

I tried doing something similar to parsing a phone number but I need to do it for each column and not just one cell.

Sample Row:
[Sample Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZyG.png)

Comment: Do you have an example of a full row of the CSV? I am wondering why there is JSON in the CSV.

Comment: Yes I am very unfamiliar with JSON, I am new to python. So the data is coming in from a powershell script that pulls data and saves it as a csv or JSON. I was using the csv to parse by using ',' as a delimiter. and imputing names for the rows.Once this data is clean, I am going to drop it into a sql database, I will be using T-SQL.